# Test Class for Before delete with Parent / Child related records

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, before-trigger

I have a Trigger that prevents a Service Agreement record to be deleted when it is currently associated with a Job record.

```
Trigger SAJobsDeletion on Support_Contract__c (before delete) {

try{    
    for(Support_Contract__c sa : Trigger.old)
    {          
        List <Job__c> j = [SELECT Id, Service_Agreement__c FROM Job__c WHERE Service_Agreement__c =: sa.Id];
        if(j.size() > 0)
        {             
            sa.adderror('Service Agreement is currently associated with a Job and cannot be deleted.');
        }
    } 
} Catch(Exception ex){  }
```

}

Below is my test class, however, it returns 0% code coverage:

```
    @isTest

public class SAJobsDeletion_TestClass {

    static testMethod void CheckServiceAgreement(){  
        Test.startTest();

        Support_Contract__c a = new Support_Contract__c();
        a.Client__c = '0035D0000067lJrQAI';
        a.Funding_Type__c = 'Cash';
        a.Funding_Management__c = 'Participant';
        a.Start_Date__c = Date.newInstance(2018, 03, 01);
        a.End_Date__c = Date.newInstance(2019, 03, 01);
        insert a; 

        Job__c j = new Job__c();
        j.Service_Agreement__c = a.Id;
        j.Contact__c = '0035D0000067lJrQAI';
        j.Region__c = 'Australia';
        j.Duration__c = 60;
        insert j;  

        try{
            delete a;           
        }Catch (DMLException e){
            System.assert(e.getMessage().contains('Service Agreement cannot be deleted.'), 'Service Agreement cannot be deleted.');
        }
        Test.stopTest();       
    }
}
```

Appreciate any help in fixing my test class.

Thanks!

Comment: Do not put queries in a loop. Do not use hard-coded ID values.

Comment: Those are exactly the things I need to revise.. but don't know how and where to start it.

Comment: @sfdcfox I've tried restructuring my code, as per your suggestion above, however I have this error: "Invalid initializer type List<Job__c> found for Map<Id,AggregateResult>: expected a Map with the same key and value types, or a valid SObject List"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, do not put queries into a loop. This can cause Bad Things to happen. A simple aggregate query can do this correctly:

```
trigger SAJobsDeletion on Support_Contract__c (before delete) {
  Map<Id, AggregateResult> jobs = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>(
    [SELECT Service_Agreement__c Id
     FROM Job__c
     WHERE Service_Agreement__c = :Trigger.old
     GROUP BY Service_Agreement__c]
  );
  for(Id contractId: jobs.keySet()) {
    Trigger.oldMap.get(contractId).addError('Service Agreement is currently associated with a Job and cannot be deleted.');
  }
}
```

Here, we ask for a list of Id values for any service contracts that have a job (lines 2-7), then, we get those records and display an error on them (lines 8-10).

**IMPORTANT**: Do not try-catch when you don't know what you're try-catching for. There's only specific problems that could cause this trigger to fail, and if you *debug* those errors, it won't prevent deletion, which is the intended purpose. If you insist on using a try-catch block, at minimum, report an error on all records and prevent deletion. In this case, *not* using a try-catch block has the same effect, but with less code.

Next, do not use hard-coded ID values. They will change from org to org, and can cause unexpected failures during deployment.

Instead, simply create a new record and assign it:

```
Contact testContact = new Contact(LastName='Test');
insert testContact;

...

a.Client__c = testContact.Id;
```

Comment: I've tried restructuring my code, as per your suggestion above, however I have this error: "Invalid initializer type List<Job__c> found for Map<Id,AggregateResult>: expected a Map with the same key and value types, or a valid SObject List"

Comment: @D.O Yeah, I forgot to put the GROUP BY in there. See edit.

Comment: Thanks for the help @sfdcfox for restructuring my code. Now my next problem is how to increase the code coverage. :)